# List Featured products and On Sale products without a shortcode in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, query-string, product

I understand WooCommerce has provided shortcodes to use for featured and sale products.

However, I can use the shortcode on a page or widget where I want to display them.

What I actually want to do is create a link for sale and one for featured products which will list on sale products and featured products respectively.

Is there anyway I can do that without the shortcode in the way product categories are listed?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. This is not a free code writing service. So after the tour please [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The following code will filter products from woocommerce product query to:

- Display featured products using `https://www.example.com/shop/?featured=1` query string
- Display on sale products using `https://www.example.com/shop/?onsale=1` query string

The code:

```
// Featured products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'filter_featured_products', 20, 1 );
function filter_featured_products( $tax_query ){
    if( isset($_GET['featured']) && $_GET['featured'] ){
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_visibility',
            'field'     => 'name', // name or term_id
            'terms'     => array('featured')
        );
    }
    return $tax_query;
}

// On sale products    
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_on_sale_products', 20, 1 );
function filter_on_sale_products( $meta_query ){
    if( isset($_GET['onsale']) && $_GET['onsale'] ){
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => '_sale_price',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. And it works exactly how  I wanted to for featured products. However, I noticed not on sale items are displayed for onsale items. Out of may be over 50 items on sale, only 2 were displayed. not sure why. Is there a way I can filter the onsale by checking for (sale price < listed price)? I am not a PHP guy and even though I can think of a logic, I cannot come up with the actual code. 

Thank you again.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec - this is a few years old but it's exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. Would you be able to advise?

As is, my query shows up blank. I'm also unsure if this is applicable to variable products. Thank you in advance.